# Does a voiceless consonant always become voiced when between 2 vowels?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

In American English, it seems when a voiceless consonant is between 2 vowels, it usually becomes voiced. For example, the "t"s in "bottle" and "water" are pronounced as "d". Does this rule apply to all the cases or are there any exceptions?

For example, does the "th" in "author" `ˈɔːθər` also follow this rule?

Answer (score 2):

No. The voiceless consonants are **Ch, F, K, P, S, Sh, T, and Th**, and most do not change in pronunciation. "T" is the exception.

Comment: Does the "k" in "cycle" sound like "g"? One native speaker corrected me once when I pronounced it as "k".

Comment: @protossshuttle, no, there’s no “g” sound in cycle.

Comment: Unless you consider the defining difference between /k/ and /g/ to be the aspiration rather than the voicing. The /k/ in "cycle" isn't aspirated, but it is voiceless

Answer (score 2):

In English, voiceless plosive consonants -  /p/, /t/, and /k/ - have allophonic variation in their aspiration. Depending on your native language and the particular dialect you are learning, the un-aspirated allophones may be confused for their corresponding voiced phones. Here is where this becomes relevant: the aspirated allophones, the ones with a little puff of air, are strictly word-initial. If it doesn't start the word, it doesn't get the little puff of air. This includes "between vowels" within a word. That native speaker who corrected your pronunciation of "cycle" was most likely correcting your aspiration, not your voicing.

The phoneme /t/ is a special case though. Astralbee covers it in their answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not a rule. Consider the word "attack" - the 'T' is pronounced similarly by both British and American English speakers, and this is placed between two vowels.

The difference is that, in some American dialects, the 'T' sound sounds more like a 'D' when pronounced as a "third sound" (sometimes also called a "tap") such as in words like "bottle", or "eating". You can hear a difference in the way a British English speaker pronounces words like this from words like "attack" or "attach", too.